# How can I disable the Windows Powershell Credential Request?

Tags: powershell, credentials, interactive

So, in my profile I attempt to download a script form [PoshCode](http://poshcode.org) if it doesn't exist:

```
Function Initialize-PoshCodeScript ([string] $ScriptName, [int] $ScriptId) {
    $ScriptFile = Join-Path $ScriptsFolder "$ScriptName.ps1"
    if (-not (Test-Path $ScriptFile)) {
        "Could not find script $ScriptName, attempting to download"
        try {
            Get-PoshCode -Id $ScriptId -PassThru | Set-Content $ScriptFile
        } catch {
            "Could not download $($ScriptName): $_"
        }
    }
}
```

One problem is that the `Get-WebFile` Cmdlet in the PoshCode module attempts to request credentials from the user as some of it's parameters have the [CredentialAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.credentialattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), even though it runs perfectly fine without supplying them.  Obviously there should be some way to disable this prompt, I was expecting `-NonInteractive` would do it, but it didn't. Running

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -c 'Import-Module PoshCode; Get-PoshCode -Id 2197 -PassThru'
```

caused the shell to lockup and wait for the dialog to be dismissed.

Comment: get-webfile has a switch that for using default cred :        `[switch]$UseDefaultCredentials`

Comment: @Kayasax There's two issues with that switch. 1: I'm not directly calling `Get-WebFile` so I can't add it. 2: These prompt's are shown before that cmdlet is even entered, simply by virtue of some parameters having the `Credential` attribute.  Maybe passing in null credentials explicitly would stop it, but again I'm not able to change the parameters being passed in.

Comment: if you know the script id, you should be able to directly call get-webfile ??